# How do I run a batch file on startup for a Win x64 machine?

Tags: 64-bit, startupscript

I know you can use autoexnt to run a batch file on startup for Windows XP, but that only seems to work for 32-bit machines.  I'm running Windows XP x64 on a box, and I need to have a script run on startup (without anyone's logging in).  Any ides?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Can also use local computer policy to configure startup and shutdown scripts.

http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/group_policy_editor.htm

Has a good walkthrough of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In your registry, accessible through "regedit" you can navigate to the following key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Add a Reg_sz type entry, doesn't matter what the key name is really, but as the value give the fully qualified path name to your program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

On startup meaning Login, or on startup meaning (before anyone logs in)?

On login, you could just put a BAT in your Startup folder.